# Make axis parallel to face

Tags: modeling

I'm making a grenade and still a blender newbie, but how do i make the x axis parallel to the face i want to move (drawn the line in pic 1).  Its off and every time I select edges to move along the axis it causes a weird movement (pic 2) when I want the grenade  faces to be aligned and not distorted...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, figured it out, orientation was set to global and needed to be set to normal

In object mode, select transformation from global to local to normal etc at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer, eg how to set the orientation to global.

Comment: In object mode, select transformation from global to local to normal etc at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

[image: Click here to switch to normal transformations]

So like @obloquy said, you can switch your orientation of the object manipulator by clicking on where the blue arrow shows in the photo and clicking the dropdown and selecting "normal". What this won't do right away, is allow you to move on the x normal.

You have to hit the grab tool with g then x then x again. Since you're in the normal axis mode, the first time you press x it will move globally (as per usual), and the 2nd time you press x, it will move along the normals! You can verify this by looking at the infobar at the bottom of your screen where it shows your actions. (unable to screenshot this piece unfortunately!). The same technique works for local space etc.

Hope this answers your questions.
Cheers, David C - Blenderforall